# Utilizando SharedPreferences para pegar a configuração padrão no Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Bom dia

Estou começando a estudar Flutter e estava tentando criar uma tela de Configuração, onde depois de configurado os parametros na tela, pode-se buscar em qualquer momento, e pra isso eu estou usando o SharedPreferences

Primeiro eu criei a Classe Parametros da seguinte maneira

```
class Parametros{
    LocalSettings settings = LocalSettings();

  String _URL_API;
  String _CodEmpresaPadrao;

  Parametros();

  String get url_api => _URL_API;

  set url_api(String value) {
  
    _URL_API = value;
  }

  String get codempresapadrao => _CodEmpresaPadrao;

  set codempresapadrao(String value){
    _CodEmpresaPadrao = value;
  }
}
```

Baseados em umas perguntas que vi aqui criei a LocalSettings

```
class LocalSettings{
  SharedPreferences preferences;

  Future<void> getInstance() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
}
```

e depois o método BuscarParametro na Parametros

```
void BuscarParametros() async {

    await settings.getInstance();
    if (settings.preferences.containsKey('URL_API'))
      _URL_API = settings.preferences.getString('URL_API');

  }
```

Mas na tela de configuração, quando eu chamo o método buscarparametro pra preencher a classe Parâmetro, e passar pra o controller do texto, chega o valor null

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que reparei no debug e que ele passa na buscarparametro, chega na linha " await settings.getInstance();" e sai do método, sem passar na hora, e depois de rodar PreencherTextoParam, ele volta na buscarparametro e roda tudo, até mesmo oque não havia sido rodado.

Queria saber se esse pode existir outro meio de estar fazendo isso, ou se posso estar concertando meu código de alguma maneira.

Comment: Por padrão, ao nomear uma função comece com letra minúscula, por exemplo `void buscarParametros()`; Já para classes utilize a primeira letra maiúscula, por exemplo `class PreencherTextParam()` (Que você já fez corretamente).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente colocar um `await` antes da chamada a `BuscarParametros()`:

```
await parametros.BuscarParametros();
setState((){
    _controllerURL.text = paremtros.url_api;
})
```

Você teria sido notificado desde erro caso tivesse marcado sua função com um retorno de um Future. Para isso, modifique a assinatura de sua função:

```
Future<void> BuscarParametros() async {
[...]
}
```

Dessa forma, se você chama essa função sem usar `await`, sua IDE irá mostrar o warning.

Por último, acredito não ser o cerne da questão, porém é interessante ter sempre certeza de retornar um valor padrão para quando a chave não está presente em cache.

Comment: Funcionou, era isso mesmo, obrigado pelas dicas e pela atenção